# Can I specify an external data source as the acceptable values of an enum in an openapi schema object?

Tags: json, enums, openapi

I'm working on an openapi (3.0.2) specification for a spring client/server. I want to be able to specify that certain fields have a limited and finite set of values -- an enum. Trouble is, I want to reference an external data file of complex objects to serve as the limited and finite list. Like so:

The reference data:

```json
“Countries”: [
    {
        “name”: “United States of America”,
        “code3”: “USA”,
        “code2”: “US”
    },
    {
        “name”: “Canada”,
        “code3”: “CAN”,
        “code2”: “CA”
    },
    {
        “name”: “Mexico”,
        “code3”: “MEX”,
        “code2”: “MX”
    }
]
```

and what I want to be able to do is require an input parameter that specifically references `code2`:

```json
“get”: {
    “parameters”: [
        “countryCode2”: {
            “in”: “query”,
            “schema”: {
                “$ref”: “referencefile.json/#/Countries/code2”
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm pretty sure this definition breaks, but I'm wondering if this is even possible without tearing my reference files apart.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean that the `countryCode` query parameter can be either `US`, `CA` or `MX`? I.e. `enum: [US, CA, MX]`. but you want to be able to fetch the possible enum values from the reference data file?

Comment: Exactly -- the range of possible values for the operation schema should be derived directly from the values of each reference object's targeted field. If I wanted `countryCode` to map to the values of `code3`, the expected domain of enum values would be `["USA", "MEX", "CAN"]`. I'm hoping that there's a way other than having to process and parse the reference data, but if not, that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `enum` in schemas requires an inline list of values and does not support `$ref` or JSONPath queries.

```
"get": {
    "parameters": [
        {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "countryCode2",
            "schema": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["US", "CA", "MX"]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What you could do is write a script that would generate OpenAPI-compatible schema definitions based on your reference data file, then you can reference those schemas in your API definition. For example:

code2.json:

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "enum": ["US", "CA", "MX"]
}
```

API definition:

```
"get": {
    "parameters": [
        {
            "in": "query",
            "name": "countryCode2",
            "schema": {
                "$ref": "path/to/code2.json"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I figured as much. JSONPath support would be the right feature request, though.

Comment: You can send a feature request here: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues